# Even I append random numbers to my api url some browser still cache the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, mobile-safari, browser-cache

I'm making the request with jQuery and the cache is disabled.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: typeParam,
    url: urlParam,
    dataType: dataTypeValue,
    data: dataParam,
    contentType: "application/json",
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    success: successFunction,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown + ". Please try again.");
    },
    cache: false
});
```

and I'm also appending a random number to the request url like this:

```
http://test.com/ajax-retrieve-menu?
random=0.12174681759599548
&menu-id=dfsdfsdfsdfsdf&store-order-id=fdsdfsdfsdfsdf
&_=1477911181817
```

But when I use iphone safari to access the page. The request got cached which is showing the previous result. How do I prevent cache on mobile? When I use safari debugging on my laptop. The URL doesn't seems appending the random number. Where did I do wrong?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure it's the browser caching and not your server?

Comment: FWIW: Adding random characters to URLs is not a remotely up-to-date practice. To correctly control the caching of your resources, set appropriate caching headers on them server-side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Em. I think so. Because on other browsers, it is working fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So if some of the requests we don't want to cache it at all, we should set the header on the server side?

Comment: @BruceMu: A resource should either be cachable (which may happen at multiple levels) or non-cachable. If you want to cache it sometimes and not cache it other times, use a different resource (e.g., different URLs). But if you want the query string trick to work, IIRC you need to ensure you're not sending caching information at all (but don't trust that, I haven't looked at this in a while -- check the HTTP 1.1 spec's caching info). In any case, good luck with solving this!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot!